# Replace values in MySQL colums from row x to row y

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, replace, rows

I'd need to replace post dates from wordpress post table.
There are >800.000 post entries with the same date because of a migration.

How can I replace the date by "from row x to row"?

For example:

- row 1 - 10.000 should have date `2013-01-02 09:20:10`
- row 10.001 - 20.000 should have date `2013-02-05 12:30:21`

and so on...

Or maybe replacing by post id?

I know there is a sql query to do this, but I can not remember which one and how to use it correctly.

Comment: You are swaing row 1-10,000 as identifed by post_id then simply right a normal update query where postid BETWEEN 1 AND 10000 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a `LIMIT` to the sql to update rows:

```
UPDATE {table} 
SET {datefield} = "{desired date}" 
WHERE {datefield} = "{bad date}" 
LIMIT 10000;
```

this will update 10000 rows at a time with a new date as desired, however it's not particularly picky about which ones get updated in which order, generally it will be in the database's internal order which is (roughly) chronological.

is there any other part of the data you can use to determine which records should be updated with which date?

Comment: Thanks I used yours in combination with Matt's suggestion in the first comment.

UPDATE table 
SET datecolumn = 'new date'
WHERE ID between 1 and 10000 

...and so on

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you asked for, but might be better. You can create distinct timestamps, as if a post has been created every X seconds:

```
update posts
set created = timestamp('2013-01-02 12:00:00') + interval id * 140 second
where 1=1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c7e0/2

You can even make them look random:

```
update posts
set created = 
  timestamp('2013-01-02 12:00:00')
  + interval id * 140 second
  + interval floor(rand()*140) second
where 1=1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b394c/1